# bootstrap popover with custom template does not show each time

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, fabricjs, popover, bootstrap-popover

i develop a web app on angularjs with fabricjs and i use the bootstrap popover to show custom messages when the user is **over** a canvas object (table with chairs object), and hide it when the mouse is **out** of an object(table).

the problem is that, the popover is not showing each time the mouse goes over an object, **if i move the mouse fast from one object to another, then no popover is shown** , i have to move the mouse very slow from one object to another in order for the popover to show.

[image]
below is show the main snippet where i create and show the popover :

/*on the mouse:over event i create and show the popover message*/

```
 canvas.on('mouse:over', function (e) {
            console.log("mouse over object");

        var table = e.target;
        $scope.tablePosition.top = table.top;
        $scope.tablePosition.left = table.left;
        $scope.tablePosition.width = table.width;
        $scope.tablePosition.height = table.height;

        var activeTab = $('.nav-tabs').find('li[class=active]').children().attr('id');

        if ((table.typeTable != 'theatre') && (activeTab == 'tab2')) {
            console.log(table.typeTable + ":" + activeTab);
            var last = table.getObjects().length;
            var name = table._objects[last - 1]._objects[1].text;
            var num = table._objects[last - 1]._objects[0].text;
            var title = '';

            $('canvas').popover({
                content: content(table, $scope.participants),
                template: popoverTemplate,
                placement: 'top',
                title: title = name != '' ? name : 'Table ' + num,
                html: true
            });

            $('canvas').popover('show');

            $('canvas').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {

                console.log('before popover show');
                if ($scope.tablePosition.left < 200) {
                    $('.popTableInfo').css('left', ($scope.tablePosition.left + ($scope.tablePosition.width / 2) + 280) + 'px');//right of the table
                }
                else {
                    $('.popTableInfo').css('left', ($scope.tablePosition.left - ($scope.tablePosition.width / 2)) + 'px');//left of the table
                }

                if ((canvas.height - $scope.tablePosition.top) < 100) {
                    $('.popTableInfo').css('top', (canvas.height - $('.popover.popTableInfo').height() / 2) + 'px'); //above table
                }
                else {
                    $('.popTableInfo').css('top', ($scope.tablePosition.top + 100) + 'px'); //normal
                }


            });

        }

    });
```

/*i destroy the popover */

```
canvas.on('mouse:out', function (e) {
        $('canvas').popover('destroy');
    });
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why have you declared `$('canvas')` in some sections but not on the destroy. Where is `canvas` declared as a variable?

Comment: hello, on mouse:out event, i destroy the popover which is on $('canvas'), the canvas variable is declared on another js file, but it works ok, as you can see on the screenshot ,that objects are drawn over the canvas object class

Comment: why are you using `.on('mouse:over'` I am not saying its wrong i have just never seen it like that, is it not just  `.on('mouseover'` and `.on('mouseout`

Comment: If you using hovering to activate it would it not be easier to implement a tooltip and then just style it like you have in the above example?

Comment: the canvas.on('mouse:out' and canvas.on('mouse:over' events are fabric's events. i use that event listeners because the tables are fabricjs objects and not DOM elements.